# How can I restore my postgresql docker volume?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I use docker-compose to start my application. One container use postgresql.

I created a script who backup container volume in a `tar.gz` file.

**backup.tar.gz**

```
├── base
├── _data
├── ...
├── pg_hba.conf
└── old.txt
```

If I inspect my files in my volume no old.txt

```
sudo tree -L 1 /var/lib/docker/volumes/application_postgresql/_data 
├── base
├── _data
├── ...
└── pg_hba.conf
```

I try to stop my container (`docker-compose stop db`), untar into `/var/lib/docker/volumes/application_postgresql/_data` and restart my container (`docker-compose restart db`). But it did not seem to work.

Files looks good

```
sudo tree -L 1 /var/lib/docker/volumes/application_postgresql/_data 
├── base
├── _data
├── ...
├── pg_hba.conf
└── old.txt
```

but my container don't want to start

```
db_1 | initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
db_1 | If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
db_1 | the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
db_1 | with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

**How can I restore my postgresql volume ?**

I know that the solution would be more elegant with a pgdump. But I want to create a backup script that don't know about the environment.

What strategy could I use ?

Comment: I think you would receive a better help at http://dba.stackexchange.com